# Ionic: side menu doesn't close before opening modal

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic3

In Ionic 3, I'm trying to open a modal from within a side menu:

> ```
>   <ion-item menuClose (click)="presentProductModal()"> Add Product</ion-item>
> ```

When the side menu is opened, the rest of the screen loses focus. When the modal link is selected, the side menu disappears. However, the modal and the main screen remain unfocused.
I'm guessing there's some timing / promise issue here, but I'm not sure what to do exactly.
Is there some workaround?

Here are two images demonstrating the issue (the "Add Product" link opens the modal):
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the menu output event: `ion-close`.

Listen for this event, and open the modal after menu has closed.

Read more about output events for menu here: [menu close event](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/#output-events)

or

Remove `menuClose` directive from ion-item. In your click function, close the menu programmatically using `close` method. Read more about it here: [Close menu programmatically.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/MenuController/#close)

This method will return a promise which will be resolved when menu is fully closed, you can then open the modal in its resolve.

```
this.menuController.close(<your menu id>).then(() => {
   this.modal.create.....
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems though that the menu is actually closing though (see second picture). Also, how exactly would I listen to that event? I've seen an examples adding the '(ionClose)="some_function()'" directive to the menu, but that would trigger a function every time the menu closes...

Comment: Yes the menu is closing, and it will still close. Its just to make sure that modal is opened after menu is closed.

Comment: So I need to listen for the ion-close event from within the function that launches after the menu option is clicked... can you show an example of how that's done? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer with a better approach. The first approach will trigger ion-close whenever menu is closed. So second approach will help you achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate the help, but unfortunately this isn't working either :/

Comment: I found the answer (see below). After trying your solution I saw that the screen quickly refocused and then lost focus again... so I realized that the problem was in the modal's HTML/CSS. Thanks again for helping me reach the answer.

Comment: glad you figured out

Answer (score 0):

The template for the modal was simply missing wrapping  tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MenuController

```
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
 }  
     If you want to close menu please use close() event

      this.menuCtrl.close()

     If you want to open menu please use open() event

      this.menuCtrl.open();
```